# ¿Como pasar datos entre formularios en AngularJS(Angular1)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Alguien sabe como puedo compartir datos entre formulario en AngularJS? Sucede que tengo una tabla y al hacer click sobre un id debe de mostrarme el detalle de ese id en otra pagina, estoy usando este servicio para almacenar el id pero al momento de redireccionarme a la otra página el id se pierde

Este es el código, disculpen si esta algo desordenado, soy nuevo usando esta herramienta

```html
<div class="divPrincipal" ng-app="SolicitudesWeb" ng-controller="SeguimientoSolicitudesController as ctrl" >
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">ID</td>
                    <td class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">DESCRIPCIÓN</td>
                    <td class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">REGISTRADA</td>
                    <td class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">SOLICITADA</td>
                    <td class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">DENEGADA</td>
                    <td class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">AUTORIZADA</td>
                    <td class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">COTIZACIÓN</td>
                    <td class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">VISTO BUENO</td>
                    <td class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">CANCELADA</td>
                    <td class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">CONCLUIDA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in ctrl.SegSolic">
                    <td><a ng-click="ctrl.param(x.IdUr)">{{x.IdUr}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{x.Descripcion}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Registrada}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Solicitada}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Denegada}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Autorizada}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Cotizacion}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.VistoBueno}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Cancelada}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Concluida}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
app.service('ServiceParametrosSolicitud', function () {
        var message = '';
        this.setMessage = function (msg) {
            message = msg;
            alert(message);
        }
        alert(message);

        this.getMessage = function () {
            return this.message;
        }
    })
    
    


app.controller('SeguimientoSolicitudesController', ['$scope','ServiceParametrosSolicitud', function ($scope, ServiceParametrosSolicitud) {
        this.SegSolic = "";
        this.SolicitudDetalle = "";
        this.Parametro = "";
        var self = this;

        solicitudContext.obtenerListaSegSolicitudes(function (resp) {
            switch (resp.ressult) {
                case "tgp":
                    self.SegSolic = solicitudContext.ListaSeguimientoSolicitudes;
                    break;
                case "notgp":
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        });

        this.param = function (Id) {            
            ServiceParametrosSolicitud.setMessage(Id);
            window.location.href = urlServer + "Home/About";
        };
    }]);
    
    
    
    

app.controller('SolicitudesController', ['$scope', 'ServiceParametrosSolicitud', function ($scope, ServiceParametrosSolicitud) {
        this.SolicitudDetalle = "";
        var self = this;
        
        var dependencia = ServiceParametrosSolicitud.getMessage();
        
        solicitudContext.obtenerListaSolicitudes(dependencia, function (resp) {
            switch (resp.ressult) {
                case "tgp":
                    self.SolicitudDetalle = solicitudContext.ListaSolicitudes;
                    break;
                case "notgp":
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: bienvenido a la comunidad de SOes, porfavor añade tu codigo para que te ayudemos.

Comment: Añade el código que has intentado para poder ayudarte. ¿AngularJS o Angular +2?

Comment: Lo que estoy usando es AngularJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas tardes seria de esta forma espero te funcione correctamente, te ayudo amigo no son formularios en este caso sino controladores, pero se te entiende :D

```js
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('ControllerOne', ['$scope', 'MyService', function ($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.Method = function () {
        MyService.setVar($scope.inputValue);
    }
}]);

App.controller('ControllerTwo', ['$scope','MyService', function ($scope, MyService) {
     $scope.$watch(function () { return MyService.getVar() }, function () {
        $scope.newvar = MyService.getVar();   
    });
}]);

App.service('MyService', function () {
    var UseVar = '';
        return {      
        getVar: function () {
            return UseVar;
        }
        ,
        setVar: function (value) {
            UseVar = value;
        },    
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="ControllerOne">
    <h2>Controller 1</2>
    <input ng-model="inputValue" />
    <input type="button" value="press" ng-click="Method()" />
  </div>
  
  <div ng-controller="ControllerTwo">
      <h2>Controller 2</h2>
    {{newvar}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Implementaré lo que me has dicho, ya te diré si me ha funcionado gracias! :D

Comment: Estare pendiente.

Comment: Gracias! Con lo que me pasaste quedó!